# Transaction using OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY not accepted by the network

Tags: p2sh

When I publish the testnet transaction below, it does not seem to be accepted by the network.

Publishing the transaction seems to work fine as it returns the txid, but the transaction does not show up on any of the blockexplorer services and does not get mined.

```
$ bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction 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
d208b659eaca2640f732b07b11ea9800c1a0bb4ffdc03aaf82af76c1787570ac
```

Here the decoded transaction.

```
$ bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction 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
{
  "txid": "d208b659eaca2640f732b07b11ea9800c1a0bb4ffdc03aaf82af76c1787570ac",
  "size": 373,
  "version": 2,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "0f064de4a4c548693c261e2a87202aaa0f54548101ae267dab7cdc5c1000dbf4",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "304402204c7cbcc610ac5ee744dc7de6fc31421217dbd066e41fd377dbe16dbd70372d3d02201e74b66967b44548c007a011d98bb42a9f22651392232b87a640dcf8ad55e1d2[ALL] 0 0 6352210399e3dde1d1853dbd99c81ba4f2c0cca351b3cceecce7cd0bd59acc5789672135210327f017c35a46b759536309e6de256ad44ad609c1c4aed0e2cdb82f62490f75f852ae6763a914a7ec62542b0d393d43442aadf8d55f7da1e303cb88210399e3dde1d1853dbd99c81ba4f2c0cca351b3cceecce7cd0bd59acc5789672135ac6755b275210399e3dde1d1853dbd99c81ba4f2c0cca351b3cceecce7cd0bd59acc5789672135ac6868",
        "hex": "47304402204c7cbcc610ac5ee744dc7de6fc31421217dbd066e41fd377dbe16dbd70372d3d02201e74b66967b44548c007a011d98bb42a9f22651392232b87a640dcf8ad55e1d20100004cad6352210399e3dde1d1853dbd99c81ba4f2c0cca351b3cceecce7cd0bd59acc5789672135210327f017c35a46b759536309e6de256ad44ad609c1c4aed0e2cdb82f62490f75f852ae6763a914a7ec62542b0d393d43442aadf8d55f7da1e303cb88210399e3dde1d1853dbd99c81ba4f2c0cca351b3cceecce7cd0bd59acc5789672135ac6755b275210399e3dde1d1853dbd99c81ba4f2c0cca351b3cceecce7cd0bd59acc5789672135ac6868"
      },
      "sequence": 5
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00036290,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 d36d5a91d3f05b2c23cf4fdcac88e4f8b50cec90 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a914d36d5a91d3f05b2c23cf4fdcac88e4f8b50cec9088ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "mznssZhbYjU5GRNupZ455TKu2BYrkmfQHC"
        ]
      }
    }, 
    {
      "value": 0.00000000,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_RETURN dbb957b39547c4b841700768d623a3f4c849743272bc7783855c9c4d",
        "hex": "6a1cdbb957b39547c4b841700768d623a3f4c849743272bc7783855c9c4d",
        "type": "nulldata"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the disassembled P2SH script.

```
OP_IF
    OP_2 0399e3dde1d1853dbd99c81ba4f2c0cca351b3cceecce7cd0bd59acc5789672135 0327f017c35a46b759536309e6de256ad44ad609c1c4aed0e2cdb82f62490f75f8 OP_2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
OP_ELSE
    OP_IF
        OP_HASH160 a7ec62542b0d393d43442aadf8d55f7da1e303cb OP_EQUALVERIFY 0399e3dde1d1853dbd99c81ba4f2c0cca351b3cceecce7cd0bd59acc5789672135 OP_CHECKSIG
    OP_ELSE 
        OP_5 OP_NOP3 OP_DROP 0399e3dde1d1853dbd99c81ba4f2c0cca351b3cceecce7cd0bd59acc5789672135 OP_CHECKSIG
    OP_ENDIF
OP_ENDIF
```

Edit: It does seem to be in the mempool (at least on my end)

```
$ bitcoin-cli getrawmempool
[
  "d4147e3350c7135ea8988eaa350d4fec00980462aa2df504b7bf946a28d1f100", 
  "2ecf4ebd5f850da38926e58673cec0b5ec87569acf6e1db888c42fbaeb7c430a", 
  "f080088e292aedc954826ba6f9c0cbbbb00364305b61203e8720ae3c8cc3c30b", 
  "b54d0c1ceaa851a165e6d8f298bcbdb2bcbd8001bb5fe743eb12de2d6335a113", 
  "89e46f5baabbf7e60cb608ff2a82b822b575983997af979cc15efd3151d94021", 
  "f097c66979654beea2cb11fe704a84f7abccb2ab8d33f40015c7a3c032845c28", 
  "82c13c01af677325ee7f7ad74604a37deb75d31ba9749c9125b64b42e5905434", 
  "68baab281fb0509c7e8badddf1300ad3e572054566c07c01fcf4598768d0a398", 
  "d208b659eaca2640f732b07b11ea9800c1a0bb4ffdc03aaf82af76c1787570ac", 
  "136b76344299ad409fbba3877ec409476ed71b243bf688c84b2cb56cf77f2db3"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with not enough miners being up to date. Eventually the transaction did go through.

https://test-insight.bitpay.com/tx/d208b659eaca2640f732b07b11ea9800c1a0bb4ffdc03aaf82af76c1787570ac